# How to assign a hotkey to “No Break”

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

How can I assign a hotkey to “No Break” function on Character panel? Or maybe write a script and create a custom panel? But how I access to this function is PS JS model?

[image: Character → No Break]

**Character** is exist in **Menu** tab but it does not in the **Keyboard Shortcuts**. So I can show/hide or assign color to this menu item and I can't assign a shortcut for it:

Comment: I deleted my answer. Annoyingly Adobe did not include handles to make No Break shortcutable without scripting.

Answer (score 2):

Photoshop has 'Dynamic Shortcuts' for the Character Panel accessible by selecting text and reopening the Character Panel menu to see the hotkeys. This provides hotkeys like Underline
(<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl / CMD</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>), however there isn't one for 'No Break'. Here is a work around instead.

Create an action called 'Apply No Break' and  create a keyboard shortcut for it.

[image: Photoshop No Break Keyboard Shortcut]

Select your text layer, click record and select 'No Break' from the Character Panel Menu.

Now whenever you select a text layer, you can type your shortcut and have it perform this

[image: Photoshop No Break Keyboard Shortcute]

The Script for this approach would be:

```
var activeLayer = app.activeDocument.activeLayer;

if(activeLayer.kind == LayerKind.TEXT) {
    activeLayer.textItem.noBreak = true;
}
```

Comment: This only works for the entire text layer. But I need to add no break only shot words. Maybe I can write a little JS to automate this process? I can not find a JS-method to “No Break”.

Like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hHmuN.png

Comment: It does'nt seem like you can run scripts while the text item is being edited. I am still working on a solution for this, so don't lose hope :)

Comment: Any this new on this idea? I have to do a ton of little ones in a photoshop comp.